# How to write a timeout decorator which can get a function or a decorated function?

Tags: python

I have the following timeout creation decorator function:

```
class TimeoutError(Exception): pass


def timeout(seconds, error_message = 'Function call timed out'):
    def decorated(func):
        print "timeout: \t" + func.__name__
        def _handle_timeout(signum, frame):
            raise TimeoutError(error_message)


        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handle_timeout)
            signal.alarm(seconds)
            try:
                print "timeout wrapper: \t" + func.__name__
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                signal.alarm(0)
            return result

        return functools.wraps(func)(wrapper)

    return decorated
```

And another decorator:

```
import inspect

class withHostAndToken(object):

    __name__ = "withHostAndToken"
    __doc__ = "Get the Host and Token for the API call"

    def __init__(self, func):
        print "withHostAndToken: \t" + func.__name__
        self.func = func
        self.HOST = ''
        self.TOKEN = ''

    def __call__(self,*args, **kwds):

        if self.HOST == '':
            self.HOST = "HOST"
        if self.TOKEN == '':
            self.TOKEN = "TOKEN"

        argsspec = inspect.getargspec(self.func)
        function_args = argsspec[0]
        if 'HOST' in function_args:
            if 'TOKEN' in function_args:
                return self.func(self.HOST , self.TOKEN , *args, **kwds)
            else:
                return self.func(self.HOST  , *args, **kwds)
        elif 'TOKEN' in function_args:
            return self.func(self.TOKEN, *args, **kwds)
```

When I try to apply both to a function I don;t get the function code to be called:

```
@timeout(2)
@withHostAndToken
def testDecorators():
    print __name__
    while True:
        print '.'

testDecorators()
```

> the output of this is:
>
> withHostAndToken:     testDecorators
>   timeout:  withHostAndToken
>   timeout wrapper:  withHostAndToken
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Isn't the problem here that your *inner* decorator class doesn't wrap property? It should retain `__name__` and `__doc__`; see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps

Comment: `__name__` and `__doc__` are not supposed to be methods. Make them regular instance attributes or properties.

Answer (score 0):

You problem does not lies there, and the chaining of decorators works fine.

Here is an example code demonstrating it with your decorators:

```
>>> @timeout(2)
@withHostAndToken
def bar(*args):
    print(*args)
    i = 0;
    while True:
        dummy = sys.stderr.write('.')


>>> bar('foo')
host token foo
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#48>", line 1, in <module>
    bar('foo')
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 10, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 19, in __call__
    return self.func(self.HOST , self.TOKEN , *args, **kwds)
  File "<pyshell#47>", line 7, in bar
    dummy = sys.stderr.write('.')
... message list truncate for brievety ...
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 4, in _handle_timeout
    raise TimeoutError(error_message)
TimeoutError: Function call timed out
>>>
```

So the function is correctly interupted after about 2 seconds as expected.

---

But in your use case, you used `time.sleep` inside the most inner function. And in Linux and other Unix, `sleep` is implemented through... `SIGALRM`!

So here is what happens:

- external decorators asks an alarm to be raised in 10 seconds
- inner decorator passes additional parameter to the function
- the function is called and calls `sleep(20)`

  - the `sleep` function call resets the alarm timeout to 20 seconds!

That's the reason why the function actually lasts 20 seconds instead of 10...

Comment: Thanks, but the way I tested it is by putting a breakpoint on the sleep line and I never got to this breakpoint.

Comment: @EranWitkon: IDEs do their best to emulate sleep and SIGALRM, but the result is not always what is expected...

Comment: Just update the question to show that it has nothing to do with sleep. the code in the new format does not print anything

Comment: @EranWitkon: Sorry but I cannot reproduce. The code works fine under IDLE and no active debugging.

Comment: Sorry, going to close the question, the code works fine

Comment: Code above works fine if you add 
        else:
            return self.func(*args, **kwds)
to the withHostAndToken. no problem with chaining the decorators.